# Draw deterministic automata

Tags: automata

I need to draw deterministic automat for L={b^i a^j b^k c^ j where i,j,k >=1} and then prove that L=?L(A) however I have no idea how to start with this problem.

Comment: The language you have given isn't one that can be matched by a finite automata.

Comment: There is deterministic push down automata for this language but not deterministic finite automata.